# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jwt, many-to-many

I followed this example to the letter :[link](https://roytuts.com/angular-spring-boot-security-jwt-authentication-and-authorization/) but I'm getting this pile of errors .I already tried to change the name of the mapping many to many changing the name of the table but without success
User signup at endpoint /signup with username, password and role(s).
The user information is stored into database.
User receives JWT (JSON Web Token) on successful signin using the same username/password at step 1.
User continues to access the endpoints for which user has role(s) as long as the token is valid. User must send JWT in HTTP header with key/value as Authorization/Bearer .

```
 2023-03-22 14:16:00.722  INFO 12260 --- [main] SQL dialect                                      HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    2023-03-22 14:16:02.129 ERROR 12260 --- [           main]          j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: mappedBy  reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
    2023-03-22 14:16:02.142 ERROR 12260 --- [           main]  o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter        Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'apiSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
    2023-03-22 14:16:03.639  INFO 12260 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService     : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2023-03-22 14:16:03.732  WARN 12260 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but  has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
     java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Ab stractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
    java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThr  eadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
  java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThr eadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
      2023-03-22 14:16:03.734  WARN 12260 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase               The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection      adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of     thread:
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:46)
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryRead(NioSocketImpl.java:261)
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:312)
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
 java.base@17.0.5/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
        app//org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
    app//org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
 app//org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
 app//org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
 app//org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:453)
 app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:542)
 app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
   app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
 app//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
 app//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
 app//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
 app//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-03-22 14:16:03.786  WARN 12260 --- [                      : Application run failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested   exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.14.jar:2.6.14]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating  bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating    bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
    at  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with  name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with  name 'integracaoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/AhrBrasil/DashBoardBackend/config/integracao/IntegracaoDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:121) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:155) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1826) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
      Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity  property: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.UsersRole.users in com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.integracao.Users.usersRoles
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:818) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]

     at     org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
    at   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1701) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1345) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1416) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha9.jar:6.0.0.Alpha9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 128 common frames omitted
```